# how to highlight the selected Item of Recycler View?

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview

I have a Recycler View with the Images loaded from the Internal Storage.
I want to Highlight the selected item when clicked.
I tried a lot of thing but it was not working.
Actually what I need is when I click any item in Recycler View that Item must go in My ArrayList and it should also get highlighted and again when I click or say unselect it must again become normal.
Here is my Code:

```
public class Images extends Fragment {
    private List<ImageHolder> imageList;
    Cursor imageCursor;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    MyImageAdapter adapter;
    ActionButton clickButton;
    List<String> listofImages;
    List<Integer> pos;
    int columnIndex;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootlayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image, container, false);
        listofImages=new ArrayList<String>();
        pos=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
        ContentResolver imageResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        Uri imageUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String projection[]={MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID,MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE};
        imageCursor = getActivity().managedQuery(imageUri, projection, null, null, null);

        clickButton= (ActionButton) rootlayout.findViewById(R.id.action_button);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootlayout.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_image);
        adapter = new MyImageAdapter(getActivity(), getImageList());

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(),recyclerView,new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
               TextView tv= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_text_all);
                    int flag=0;

                    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    imageCursor = getActivity().managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            projection, 
                            null,       
                            null,
                            null);
                    columnIndex = imageCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                    imageCursor.moveToPosition(position);
                    // Get image filename
                    String imagePath = imageCursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    if (listofImages.contains(imagePath)){
                        Log.d("Contains Test","Yes");
                        listofImages.remove(imagePath);
                        pos.remove(position);
                    } else {
                        listofImages.add(imagePath);
                        pos.add(position);
                        Log.d("Contains Test","No");
                    }

                String s=listofImages.size()+" "+imagePath;
                Log.d("Inserted",s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {}
        }));

        clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i=0;i<listofImages.size();i++){
                    stringBuilder.append(listofImages.get(i)+"\n");
                }
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),stringBuilder,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return rootlayout;
    }

    public List<ImageHolder> getImageList() {
        imageList=new ArrayList<ImageHolder>();

        if(imageCursor!=null && imageCursor.moveToFirst()){

           int titleColumn = imageCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE);
            int idColumn = imageCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);

            do {
                ImageHolder img=new ImageHolder();
                img.id=imageCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                img.title=imageCursor.getString(titleColumn);

                img.iconid= imageCursor.getInt(idColumn);


                imageList.add(img);
            }
            while (imageCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return  imageList;
    }
}
```

This is my Adapter Class:

```
public class MyImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyImageAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<ImageHolder> data= Collections.emptyList();
    private ClickListener clickListener;
    int width,height;

    public MyImageAdapter(Context context, List<ImageHolder> data1) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data1;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_row, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try{
            ImageHolder current=data.get(position);
            holder.title.setText(current.title);

            Log.d("Imageid:"+current.iconid,"");
            Uri IMAGE_URI = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + current.iconid);

            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(decodeUri(IMAGE_URI), 200, 200, true);
            holder.img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
    public void deleteRecyclerData(int position){
        data.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }


    private Bitmap decodeUri(Uri selectedImage) throws FileNotFoundException {
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
               context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o);

        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 100;

        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                break;
            }
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o2);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        TextView title;
      // TextView artist;
        ImageView img;
        CheckBox checkBox;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_text_all);
            img= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_image_all);
            img.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {}
    }
    public interface ClickListener{
        public void itemClicked(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

Comment: may this help u   http://amolsawant88.blogspot.in/2015/08/easy-way-to-highlight-selected-rowitem.html

Comment: Try the link  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46677018/1308990

Comment: You can check [this tutorial](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/highlight-selected-item-recycler-view/) and [this example in GitHub](https://github.com/thedeveloperworldisyours/FullRecyclerView/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/thedeveloperworldisyours/fullrecycleview/updateData)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can use a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) to achieve the desired effect.

**Example**

Create a new *Drawable resource file* in your `drawable` directory with the following content:

**selector_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Color when the row is selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- Standard background color -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_selected="false" />
</selector>
```

Now simply use this `StateListDrawable` as the background in the row-layout of your `RecyclerView`

**row_recyclerview.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_row">

    <!-- row content -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now as soon as the `onClick()` method in your adapter is called you simply need to do the following:

```
// myBackground is the RelativeLayout root of your row
myBackground.setSelected(true);
```

The rows' background will have the color (in this case *darker_gray*) as long as you call `myBackground.setSelected(false)`. Of course you should create a [SparseBooleanArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html) for example in order to know which row is selected and which isn't since the rows will be reused when scrolling.

**Edit: Remember selected items**
The idea behind the *SparseBooleanArray* is to remember the items which are selected. Following a sample on how to use it:

```
public class MyImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyImageAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private SparseBooleanArray selectedItems;

    // Other stuff [...]

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // Set the selected state of the row depending on the position
        holder.myBackground.setSelected(selectedItems.get(position, false));
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              // Save the selected positions to the SparseBooleanArray 
              if (selectedItems.get(getAdapterPosition(), false)) {
                  selectedItems.delete(getAdapterPosition());
                  myBackground.setSelected(false);
              }
              else {
                  selectedItems.put(getAdapterPosition(), true);
                  myBackground.setSelected(true);
              }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help, but when I am scrolling my RecyclerView  the other item is also getting Selected. Is it because I didn't used SparseBooleanArray. If so would you please explain me how to do it.

Comment: @KuldeepDubey Exactly. Since you're not resetting the selected state of the rows, the recycled views are still selected. Please see my edit for an example on how to use the *SparseBooleanArray*.

Comment: @reVrese, Thanks It helped, I did some changes in my Adapter class with the help of your code and it worked.

Comment: @reVerse I really like this method. The only problem is that when an item and is partly hidden it doesn't bounce to be entirely in the screen (as opposed to other methods I've seen on SO). Any idea on how to do that ?

Comment: @Ced I'm not entirely sure what you mean. The method of my post simply sets the background depending on the state so it shouldn't have any effect on the scrolling behaviour of the `RecyclerView`?!

Comment: @reVerse Yes exactly ! I've seen other methods that when you click on an item and the item is partly off the screen the recyclerview will automatically scroll to show the entire item. I hope that makes sens. I was just asking if you had an idea on how to do that.

Comment: @Ced I guess those methods call [notifyItemChanged(int pos)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged%28int%29). This will update the row completely and, if I remember correctly, scroll to the given position.

Comment: @reVerse I found how to do it. For information notifyItemChanged didn't seem to work. So I had to call this :             fragment.getRecyclerView().smoothScrollToPosition(getPosition());
from within my onclick method.

Comment: Hey @reVerse thanks, I really liked this method of using SparseBooleanArray. In my case I can only have one item selected at a time. How can I deselect the previous selected row once a new one is selected?

Comment: @DanielJulio What about saving the position of the selected item separately in a variable? Once the selection changes you can simply deselect the old row since you know the position of the previous item that has been selected.

Comment: @reVerse will I have to notifyItemChanged with said position?

Comment: @reVerse Thanks so much!

Comment: what to do if my holder does not recognize background ?

Comment: `myBackground` is basically only the reference to the root layout which has the drawable selector - in this example it's the `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: I would remove `android:state_pressed="false"`, otherwise color will change when they press and hold on a selected item.

Comment: How do we show the first row as selected when the RecyclerView is loaded for the first time. I tried it by using a Boolean but it did not work with the scrolling. It keeps the top most row selected. How do I achieve this?

Comment: @Bot Well just check in #onBindViewHolder the position and set the selected state e.g.: if(position == 0) holder.myBackground.setSelected(true);

Comment: @reVerse, that leads to the first row always being selected. I tried a few things but it remains selected always.

Comment: I think I don't get what you wanna achieve. Maybe it's a good idea to ask a new question.

Comment: @reVerse, well, I am just trying to show the First row in the `RecyclerView` as selected, when the 'RecyclerView' is loaded first time. The data in the corresponding fragment is as per this row. Now when a new row is selected, this one should get deselected. That's not happening. In case you do not get me, I will ask a new question.

Comment: @Bot Okay. There're a few options but I think we're kind of limited in the comments section. So just post a new question and I'm happy to look at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117170/discussion-between-bot-and-reverse).

Comment: @ReVerse I tried the method you recommended in chat to save the selected position in an integer field.  I am only trying to highlight one CardView item with an onLongClick().  My problem is the first item added to the RecyclerView list already has the item highlighted before the onLongClick method is called.  Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: @AJW Checkout [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38349951/982852). Just change the `selectedPosition` to -1 to prevent an initial selection of a row.

Comment: @ReVerse:  Excellent, that worked.  I have one more fix now.  CardVeiws are randomly being highlighted after the correct CardView is deleted.  And the CardViews are being highlighted without the call to OnLongLick().  Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Do you reset the `selectedPosition` variable (e.g. to -1) once a `CardView` is deleted? That would be necessary in order to prevent a selection once the `RecyclerView` gets refreshed.

Comment: Ah yes I have not added that.  The reset would be so that the selection does not carry over to the refreshed positions?

Comment: @AJW Exactly, yep.

Comment: what is pos here ?

Comment: @user3475052 Sorry, obviously this should be also `getAdapterPosition()`. I'll fix it.

Comment: @reVerse I'll implement your code in my adapter but no efftect on my layout .I need one item is highlighed everytime but in your code save the click but it does not effect on my code .Please suggest me the right way

Comment: @reVerse please help me in this link  https://stackoverflow.com/q/53737022/8348768

Comment: I never use xml for drawables, do you have this xmls codes on programatically version ? (java insted of xml)

Comment: @ArthurMelo You can create StateListDrawables programatically - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6501716/982852) SO question for example

Answer (score 36):

there is no selector in RecyclerView like ListView and GridView but you try below thing it worked for me

create a selector drawable as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<item android:state_pressed="true">
   <shape>
         <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
   </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape>
       <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

then set this drawable as background of your RecyclerView row layout as

```
android:background="@drawable/selector"
```

Comment: I wish I could vote your question up every time it saves me! Thanks!

Comment: make sure to also add android:clickable="true" to you RecyclerView row layout

Comment: this works for the pressed effect, not the selected one

Answer (score 21):

You can add this to your row_item.xml

```
android:clickable="true"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

For example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"

<!-- row content -->
```

If android version is Lolipop or greater, selector comes with ripple. And a highlight for other version. Hope it helps

Comment: this works for the pressed effect, not the selected one

Comment: You did not answer the question as this only solves the pressed condition

Answer (score 4):

I have tried several ways for hours and here is the two solutions I came out with. **Both solutions** assume I have my `RecyclerView` declared as follows:

**activity.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Nothing special here, just a regular `RecyclerView` declaration. Now let's see the other files, starting with the most easy and viable solution.

## First solution (XML only)

**layout/item.xml**

The two important attributes here in the item's root `ViewGroup` are `background` and `clickable`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_item"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

**drawable/selector_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/background_item_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/background_item"
        />

</selector>
```

## Second solution (XML + Java)

**item.xml**

No `background` nor `clickable` attribute here.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

**Adapter.java**

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            itemView.setOnTouchListener(itemTouchListener);
        }
    }

    ...
    private View.OnTouchListener itemTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_item_event_pressed);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    // CANCEL triggers when you press the view for too long
                    // It prevents UP to trigger which makes the 'pressed' background permanent which isn't what we want
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                    // OUTSIDE triggers when the user's finger moves out of the view
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_item_event);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    };

    ...
}
```

I highly recommend using the first solution as it's easier to maintain and more powerful as it also allows you to add ripple effects (in the `drawable/background_item...` XML files), which I believe isn't possible with solution 2.

Comment: have you  got an answer for always highlighted one item in recycle adapter class

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code out of Adapter

```
LinearLayoutManager RvLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager)rootlayout.getLayoutManager();
View itemSelected = RvLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(position);
itemSelected.setBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a selector drawable with `android:state_focused="true"` attribute as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item>
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item
                android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"
                android:state_focused="true" />
        </selector>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

then set this drawable as background of your RecyclerView row layout as

```
android:background="@drawable/selector"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you manage to use an observable pattern flavor such as Otto or AndroidRx, you can follow how to highlight the background as explained above, and for each viewHolder's itemView you can subscribe to the observable and unsubscribe when it detaches from your recyclerview like I did here:

https://github.com/juanmendez/jm_android_dev/blob/master/01.fragments/06.fragments_with_rx/app/src/main/java/info/juanmendez/android/recyclerview/ui/listing/recyclerview/CountryHolder.java#L49

By the way for a quick demo my itemView is using linearLayout, so it was easy to set background color as yellow.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This solution is more of an interactive look like the tableView in IOS. It'll highlight then unhighlight the cells.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Cell holder, final int position) {
    if(requests != null) {
        holder.setView(requests.get(position), context);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                Logs.print("In OnClickListener", position + " selected");
            }
        });

        holder.itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Logs.print("In Touch Handler", "A press has started");
                        v.setSelected(true);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Logs.print("In Touch Handler", "A press has been completed");
                        v.setSelected(false);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        Logs.print("In Touch Handler", "gesture aborted");
                        v.setSelected(false);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include comments or some sort of explanation for your code. Why would you use both a Click Listener as well as a Touch Listener? And how would this allow someone to both select and un-select an item?

Comment: @SammyT Hey Sammy sorry for that. This implementation will highlight then unhighlight when tapped and will remain highlighted when long clicking. Also it'll unhighlight after keeping a cell highlighted when long clicking then scrolling away.