# Reset colours for previous CardViews in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have an `onClick` method that sets the current `CardView` to a colour, but then all the previous `CardViews` that had their`onClick` method invoked also have their colour changed. What I am trying to do is to reset all the other `CardViews` to their original colour and set the current `CardView` to a different colour.

This is my code:

```
public ViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);
    cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    });
}
```

So the above method sets the background colour for that `cardview` which is great but I want the others to return back to their original colours. How would I go about doing that?

Thanks

Comment: Obiviously you should "store" state in view or viewholder but in underlaying data

Comment: I don't my thing is like for each cardview which is the problem - the way I wrote it is such that it applies only to one cardview

Comment: `setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)` <= is kind of "storing" state in view ... + fact that it is a RecyclerView = problems

Comment: why whats wrong about using a `cardview` in a `recyclerview`? It works but then all the other `cardviews` that were previously set are of the same colour

Comment: there is nothing wrong ... setting things(like background color) not based on underlaing data **is**  ...

Comment: i see, what is the solution?

Comment: I think this is the solution you are looking for - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983848/how-to-highlight-the-selected-item-of-recycler-view

Answer (score 0):

you use simple list view? if so than it is not correct behaviour. why you just do not set list.setOnItemClick where you can set new color into adapter and call onDataSetChanged?

Comment: Sorry its a recyclerview. I just need some help resetting the other colours of the cardview except the selected one

Comment: you can do it by updating adapter's items.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367599/how-to-update-recyclerview-adapter-data

Comment: how? i am talking about the background data here OF THE CARDVIEW

Comment: @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }

Comment: OMG why do I even bothering posting here. You havent even answered the question. Your code is already in my OP - sorry I don't think you understood my question - never mind