# Items of RecyclerView are not showing correctly

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

In my `onBindViewHolder` of my `RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.ViewHolder>` when user clicks on `cardview` a button becomes visible. But when I'm scrolling recyclerview some other items buttons are shown as visible too. Why is this happening?

this is my code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    viewHolder.card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (viewHolder.content_layout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                viewHolder.content_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.address.setMaxLines(2);
                viewHolder.attribute.setMaxLines(2);
            } else {
                viewHolder.content_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.address.setMaxLines(8);
                viewHolder.attribute.setMaxLines(8);
            }
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once you start scrolling down the list your views get recycled. This means a previously inflated ViewHolder (some that gets created in `onCreateViewHolder`) is reused.
So what you have to do is to remember the clicked positions (e.g. via a [SparseBooleanArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html)) and check in `onBindViewHolder` whether the view should be visible (previously clicked) or not.

You can find a basic usage example of the `SparseBooleanArray` in [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983848/how-to-highlight-the-selected-item-of-recycler-view/29984220#29984220) post

Answer (score 6):

The 'other' visible items buttons are the ones using the same viewholder that was modified in the callback. So because viewholders (and views) are recycled :

- They should only store information that can be retrieved each time the viewholder is bound to a position.
- Anything that may be changed in the views state should be refreshed in `onBindViewHolder()`

In your case you should store the 'is selected' somewhere else **and** reset the visibility and maxlines in `onBindViewHolder()` (not only in the callback)

Answer (score 5):

Good idea is to make a class object with all data you need for one item in recycler view, also add there one boolean `isItemWasClicked` and inside `onBindViewHolder()` check this boolean and make buttons visible or not.
For example:

```
public class OneItemOfList{
    int priceToDisplay;
    String name;
    String date;
    boolean wasClicked;
}

public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OneItemOfList.ViewHolder> {
ArrayList<OneItemOfList> items;
...
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    viewHolder.view.setText(items.get(position).name);
    if (items.get(position).wasClicked)
        viewHolder.button.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        viewHolder.button.setVisible(View.GONE);
    viewHolder.view2.setOnClickListener(...
        OnClick(...){
            items.get(position).wasClicked = !items.get(position).wasClicked;
        });
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

create an array for example Boolean array, and when each position clicked, set true in same position of array. and in onBindViewHolder check if that array[position] is true set that item visible if.

Comment: i'm doing that with `arraylist.get(position).type`