# Changing color of Recyclerview when clicking an item(Error)

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have to create an applictaion using recycler view but when I click an item in a `RecyclerView` the whole color of `RecyclerView` and `CardView` is changed
I don't know how it happened I think it is an error but don't show any error in error log

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.jhjiko.infouyt.TimelineFragment"
    android:id="@+id/timelineid">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_datepicker"
        android:background="#84FFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Sort by day" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_datepicker">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#EFEBE9">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

and here is the code for `CardView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#454E57"
        android:animationCache="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#09ADF5"
            android:elevation="1dp">

            <TextView
                android:text="Reportname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txt_report"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                android:textColor="#F9FBE7" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Branchname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txt_branch"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:textColor="#F9FBE7" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:text="username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="27dp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:id="@+id/txt_user"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:textColor="#F9FBE7" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewdate"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.11"
                android:editable="false"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="date"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:textColor="#F9FBE7" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:text="Cash        "
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:editable="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:foregroundGravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:textColor="#F9FBE7" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewcash"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:editable="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:textColor="#F9FBE7" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone">

             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewid"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:editable="false"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:text="Description"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:editable="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                tools:ignore="RtlCompat"
                android:textColor="#F9FBE7" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewdesc"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.02"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:minLines="2"
                android:maxLines="10"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:editable="false"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:textColor="#F9FBE7" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/imagePhoto"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:layout_gravity="left|start"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/imagegallery"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_gravity="right|end"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

here is my code for adapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import java.util.List;

public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ImageLoader imageLoader, photoLoader;
    private Context context;
    //List of superHeroes
    List<Content> superHeroes;

    public CardAdapter(List<Content> superHeroes, Context context){
        super();
        //Getting all the superheroes
        this.superHeroes = superHeroes;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.content_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v,context,superHeroes);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try {
            Content superHero = superHeroes.get(position);
            imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

            imageLoader.get(superHero.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.drawable.noimg,R.drawable.noimg));
            photoLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getPhotoLoader();
            photoLoader.get(superHero.getPhotoUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.photoView, R.drawable.noimg, R.drawable.noimg));
            if (superHero.getImageUrl().length() > 0) {
                holder.imageView.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
                holder.imageView.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.noimg);
                holder.imageView.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.noimg);
            } else {
                holder.imageView.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.noimg);
            }
            if (superHero.getPhotoUrl().length() > 0) {
                holder.photoView.setImageUrl(superHero.getPhotoUrl(), photoLoader);
                holder.photoView.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.noimg);
                holder.photoView.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.noimg);
            } else {
                holder.photoView.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.noimg);
            }
            holder.textViewcash.setText(superHero.getName());
            holder.textViewid.setText(String.valueOf(superHero.getReportid()));
            holder.textViewdesc.setText(superHero.getCreatedBy());
            holder.textViewdate.setText(superHero.getFirstAppearance());
            holder.textViewuser.setText(superHero.getUser());
            holder.textViewreport.setText(superHero.getReport());
            holder.textViewbranch.setText(superHero.getBranch());

       }catch (Exception ex){
       }
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return superHeroes.size();
   }

   class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
       private final List<Content> superHeros;
       public NetworkImageView imageView;
       public NetworkImageView photoView;
       public TextView textViewcash;
       public TextView textViewid;
       public TextView textViewdesc;
       public TextView textViewdate;
       public TextView textViewuser;
       public TextView textViewbranch;
       public TextView textViewreport;
       Context context;
       public ViewHolder(View itemView,Context context,List<Content>superHeroes) {

           super(itemView);
           this.superHeros=superHeroes;
           this.context=context;
           itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
           photoView=(NetworkImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagegallery);
           imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagePhoto);
           textViewcash = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewcash);
           textViewid= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewid);
           textViewdesc= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewdesc);
           textViewdate= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewdate);
           textViewuser=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_user);
           textViewbranch=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_branch);
           textViewreport=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_report);
       }


       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           try {
               int position = getAdapterPosition();
               Content content = this.superHeros.get(position);
               String reportid = String.valueOf(content.getReportid());
               String reportname=content.getReport();
               String url=content.getImageUrl();
               String photo=content.getPhotoUrl();
               Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, showimage.class);
               intent.putExtra("img_id",url);
               intent.putExtra("photo_id",photo);
               intent.putExtra("id", reportid);
               intent.putExtra("report", reportname);
               this.context.startActivity(intent);
           }
           catch (Exception ex){
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

please help me to find a solution to solve this problem, thanks in advance

Comment: see this its looks like same may be it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/29984220/4427519

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 please refer my adapter code

Answer (score 1):

I think you had written a code to change color of Views on "OnClick" event. So if you had done that remove or comment it. For clear answer please share your "OnClick" event code.

Comment: @Saqip Saikh i don't use any code to change colour,  only use xml to change color i don't know why this is happened please help me to solve this thanks in advance