# Can't getTag() of itemview after scrolling anymore

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

here's what I wanna do: I want items in `recyclerview` to be highlighted when clicked once and back to normal when clicked again.

so I have a `recyclerview`. naturally I have an `adapter` too. inside adapter is my `viewholder` class where I have an `onClickListener` set on `itemview`.

whenever it is clicked I `getTag()`. if it's value is `"false"` I highlight `itemview` and `setTag("true")`, if its value is `"true"` I color `itemview` back to normal and `setTag("false")`.

**So far everything working fine but now comes the problem:**
when I scroll up (so that item is out of sight) and down again value of tag seems gone also highlighting of item.

I tried `setIsRecycable(false)` but isn't working.

How can I preserve tags/highlighting on those items??

**Edit:**
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,View.OnLongClickListener {

```
final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rl1);
final RelativeLayout rl2 = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rl2);
public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    itemView.setTag("f");


        //text layout
        mSenderUsernameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_username);
        mSenderMessageView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.et_message);
        mSenderTimeView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);

        mSenderUsernameView.setOnClickListener(this);
        mSenderMessageView.setOnClickListener(this);
        mSenderTimeView.setOnClickListener(this);
        rl.setOnClickListener(this);
        rl2.setOnClickListener(this);

        }   

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == rl.getId() || v.getId() == rl2.getId() || v.getId() == mSenderUsernameView.getId() ||
            v.getId() == mSenderMessageView.getId() || v.getId() == mSenderTimeView.getId()) {


        //check if msg is selected or not
        //not selected
        if(itemView.getTag().toString().equals("f")){                rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_msg_color_roundings);
            rl2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_msg_color_roundings);
            itemView.setTag("t");
        }
        //selected
        else if(itemView.getTag().toString().equals("t")){
            //Toast.makeText(context, mMessages.get(getAdapterPosition()).getUsername()
            //+ " at " + mPos + " is " + va, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.msg_color_roundings);
            rl2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.msg_color_roundings);

            itemView.setTag("f");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post code of your adapter otherwise none of us will be able to help

Comment: please read these: [ask] & [mcve]

Comment: I posted my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Key was to keep track of selected items using SparseBooleanArray not tags. Selection of items is done with the help of StateListDrawable

[how to highlight the selected Item of Recycler View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983848/how-to-highlight-the-selected-item-of-recycler-view)

Answer (score 0):

A way to keep track of which positions in your RecyclerView have been clicked is by using an internal dataset in your Adapter, like so:

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.ViewHolder> {

boolean[] dataset;
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;

    public ViewHolder(RelativeLayout v) {
        super(v);
        mRelativeLayout = v;
    }
}

public RVAdapter(boolean[] dataset) {
    this.dataset = dataset;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mRelativeLayout.setTag(position);
    holder.mRelativeLayout.setEnabled(dataset[position]);
    holder.mRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = (int) view.getTag();
            dataset[position] = !dataset[position];
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataset.length;
}
}
```

In this example the view is just enabled/disabled but it illustrates how you could achieve what you need.

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer. have you used that code before? does it actually work? haven't found time to try it out yet

Comment: I haven't used this exact code but I've used similar implementations several times. Whenever you get the time you might want to debug with a bunch of breakpoints to see for yourself how the code behaves.