# updating drawable image runtime in android

Tags: java, android, drawable

I am trying to update android image **onClick** which was created dynamically in a popup,  if i click the image the image have to be replaced with the smaller size of the image and it will redirect to another fragment after fragment is loaded the resource have to become normal size i tried with the following code.

```
  if (MenuButton[0].getId() == v.getId()) {                
        MenuButton[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.Small_menu_general); //updating here
        myLog.v(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber(), "Select Menu", "General Setting");
        Product_Location(Vars.Menu_General);
        GlobalClass.fragment = new Run_Screen();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, 0, 0, R.anim.fade_out).replace(R.id.fragment_place, GlobalClass.fragment).commit();
        HideMainMenu();
    }
```

and in HideMainMenu() i am trying to update it to normal

```
public void HideMainMenu() {
  Menu_Frame_1.clearAnimation();
  Menu_Frame_1.startAnimation(Menu_Hide_Anim);
  Menu_Frame_2.clearAnimation();
  Menu_Frame_2.startAnimation(Menu_Hide_Anim);
  Main_Menu.startAnimation(MenuHideRotation);
  MenuButton[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.Normal_menu_general); //retaining to normal here
}
```

Comment: Why don't you make a selector of them with the normal image and smaller image.

Comment: i don't have any idea about selector i am new to android, thanks i will try

Comment: @NigamPatro i guess i cant use selector  because i am not using xml drawable it was image drawable set via java still is it possible to use it?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: i tried with this tutorial http://www.compiletimerror.com/2014/03/android-button-selector-tutorial-with.html here they have used xml is there any tutorial to achieve it with java

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39530365/5567009

Comment: ok, thank you  i will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use state to achieve this

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
 states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
 getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.Small_menu_general));
 MenuButton[0].setImageDrawable(states);
```